# How to use proc mianalyze to predict test set

Tags: sas, logistic-regression, sas-studio

I am using a logistic regression with Mulitple imputation. How do I use the PROC MIANALYZE output (combined parameter estimates) to predict the test test labels ?

My code for the proc mianalyze is as below;

```
proc mianalyze parms=a_mvn; 
modeleffects Intercept DONCntCardP1 DONAvgCardP1 DONTimeLast DONTimeFirst;      
ods output ParameterEstimates=p_mvn;
run;
```